# .exrc file in home dir not effective

Tags: vim, rhel

I made a simple `.exrc` vim config file in my home directory on RHEL 5.8.  Here are the contents:

```
set nu
```

However, when I go into vim, the line number are not shown.  It may be worth noting that I am logged in as a shared application user ID.  I have access to other RHEL 5.8 hosts here at work as well under my own user and .exrc file does in fact work.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file is for vi (or nvi). You want .vimrc.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  But how come `.exrc` works with my other RHEL user as well as on my home laptop, which is Fedora 16?

Comment: Perhaps some setting or some alias, I can't know.

Comment: The preferred configuration file for nvi is `~/.nexrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Vim only reads [`~/.exrc`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#.exrc) if it hasn't found a `~/.vimrc`. Chances are that you already have a `.vimrc` file on that machine, but not on the other machines where adding the setting in `.exrc` works.

You can put `source ~/.exrc` in your `~/.vimrc` to read your generic vi settings from `~/.exrc` and have other vim-specific settings. If you want to read `~/.exrc` only if it's present, use

```
if filereadable('~/.exrc')
    source ~/.exrc
endif
```